# Excluding specific files in a nested directory using ansible synchronize module

Tags: ansible

I have the following ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: loghost
  tasks:
    - name: Get logs
      synchronize:
        src: /home/app/logs/
        dest: /central/logs/applogs/{{inventory_hostname}}
        dirs: yes
        mode: pull
        rsync_opts:
            - "--exclude=backup"
            - "--exclude=target"
            - "--exclude=internal/client/.ods"
            - "--exclude=internal/exchange/.ods"
```

where I am trying to synchronize a directory that contains sub-directories.

I want to exclude specific files with a specific file format in the subdirectories specifically from the applogs/internal directory. I've tried specifying the path as shown above but Im still getting these files when using the synchronize module. Is there a way for me to exclude a the main directory's subdirectory's files using --exclude?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which ansible version do you run with?

Which folders or files are not excluded in list?

```
        - "--exclude=backup"
        - "--exclude=target"
        - "--exclude=internal/client/.ods"
        - "--exclude=internal/exchange/.ods"
```

I test with `ansible v2.0.2` and it is fine to exclude subfolders or file in subfolder.

Comment: This may be it as I'm using version 1.9.2

Comment: hi, i tried this but it does not work :( it does not exclude the file i mentioned it to exclude
rsync_opts:
           - "--exclude=/opt/QuadplayApps/UPC_New/epc/bin/standalone.conf"
the path is on source ( control ) machine

Comment: @VasanthNagKV for rsync, the path is always relative. It won't honor absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this with variables as follows:

```
exclude_files: 
  - file1
  - file2

- name: Copy all files except excludes
  synchronize:
    src: src_folder/
    dest: dest_folder/
    rsync_opts: |
        {% for s in exclude_files %}
        "--exclude={{ s }}"
        {% endfor %}
```